# Can you use Function in Oracle-Sql as DML?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

So I got an assigment to Perform the following task.

```
   Create a simple program to demonstrate the use of stored functions for
       a) Retrieving formatted information by giving the employee id.
       b) Performing DML commands (Insert, Update and Delete)
       c) Checking palindrome String
```

The following table is used

```
SQL> desc Employee01;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 ENAME                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(20)
 HIREDDATE                                          DATE
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(38)
```

I have done the first two but the palindrome one I don't know how to start. Help would be appreciated.

Edit: Got help in DML
Palindrome Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FPal(
  str VARCHAR2)
     RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
     l VARCHAR2;
     t VARCHAR2;
     res  VARCHAR2 (130);
  BEGIN
     FOR i IN REVERSE 1..Length(s) LOOP  
        l := Substr(str, i, 1);
        t := t  
             ||'' 
             ||l;  
    END LOOP;  

    IF t = str THEN 
      dbms_output.Put_line(t  
                           ||'' 
                           ||' is palindrome');  
    ELSE 
      dbms_output.Put_line(t  
                           ||'' 
                           ||' is not palindrome');  
    END IF;  
     RETURN (res);
  END FPal;
 /
```

Comment: mysql <> sql server <> Oracle. I've removed mysql and sql server, in future, please only tag products involved in the question

Comment: Well, where are you stuck? What have you tried, and why didn't that work?

Comment: Actually got help in DML now I'm stuck in Palindrome

Comment: Same question applies: what have you tried?

Comment: Your `fins` function will return null because you don't give any value to `emp_detail`. (By the way, `return` doesn't require brackets.)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Updated the code

Comment: You have edited your question to include code from an answer. Why did you do that? If you found the solution helpful the correct thing would be to **upvote and/or accept** the answer. If you have questions regarding the solution the correct thing would be to **comment** on the answer. Editing your question as you have done merely confuses everybody else.

Comment: Addressing your subject line only - "Can you use Function in Oracle-Sql as DML?".  Yes, you can, but it is not a proper use of _functions_.  That may have been your homework assignment, but please, please, please do take that to mean doing dml in a function is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible fixed function:

```
    SQL> set serveroutput on
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FPal(
      2    str VARCHAR2)
      3       RETURN  VARCHAR2
      4    IS
      5       l CHAR;
      6       t VARCHAR2(128);
      7    BEGIN
      8       FOR i IN REVERSE 1..Length(str) LOOP
      9          l := Substr(str, i, 1);
     10          t := t  || l;
     11      END LOOP;
     12  
     13      IF t = str THEN
     14        dbms_output.Put_line(t  ||' is palindrome');
     15        return 'TRUE';
     16      ELSE
     17        dbms_output.Put_line(t  ||' is not palindrome');
     18        return 'FALSE';
     19      END IF;
     20    END FPal;
     21   /

    Function created.

    SQL> show errors
    No errors.
```

Testing:

```
    SQL> select fpal('ABBA') from dual;

    FPAL('ABBA')
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TRUE

    ABBA is palindrome
    SQL> select fpal('BABA') from dual;

    FPAL('BABA')
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FALSE

    ABAB is not palindrome
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: split input string into rows and *merge* them back, backwards. Compare those two values and decide.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_pal (par_val in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  2    l_val varchar2(200) := replace(par_val, ' ', '');
  3    l_rev varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    select listagg(regexp_substr(l_val, '[^.]', 1, level), '')
  6           within group (order by level desc)
  7      into l_rev
  8      from dual
  9      connect by level <= length(l_val);
 10
 11    return 'palindrome: ' || case when l_rev = l_val then 'YES'
 12                                  else 'NO'
 13                             end;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select 'little' from dual union all
  4     select 'radar'  from dual union all
  5     select '12321'  from dual union all
  6     select 'ana voli milovana' from dual
  7    )
  8  select col, f_pal(col) result
  9  from test;

COL               RESULT
----------------- ------------------------------
little            palindrome: NO
radar             palindrome: YES
12321             palindrome: YES
ana voli milovana palindrome: YES

SQL>
```